# make activation for windows phone

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-8.1

I just searched a little But I didn't find anything.
I want to make activation for my app. I want to make a file in the system and when person remove my app, file doesnt remove because I want to check activation after person install it again.
Is there any way to do that because I do that but when I reinstall app, File removed.
Its my way to do that but If you can say better way, please help me.
I am sorry for my English.
Thanks.

Comment: What are you trying to prevent the second time the user installs the app? And do you care about the user installing it more than once (possibly on different devices), or it being installed more than once on the same device (possibly by different people)?

Comment: I want to make activation for my app. when person activate app, for other time person install app on that device, he doesn't need to activate that again. He actives app one time on special device and for other time that he reinstall it, app active automatically. Do you understand that?

Comment: But if they buy a new device do they have to activate again? If they resell the device, does the new owner have to activate?

Comment: Yes. It's true. maybe I have change my method.

Answer (score 0):

AS now files are saved in application storage which gets deleted when app is uninstalled.You can save your text file to your external storage if it is available.

```
     StorageFolder externalDevices = Windows.Storage.KnownFolders.RemovableDevices;

            // Get the first child folder, which represents the SD card.
            StorageFolder sdCard = (await externalDevices.GetFoldersAsync()).FirstOrDefault();

            if (sdCard != null)
            {
                // An SD card is present and the sdCard variable now contains a reference to it.
                var output1 = await sdCard.CreateFileAsync("Test.txt", CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists);
            }
            else
            {
                // No SD card is present.
            }
```

Comment: thanks for answer But it's work when sd card is available. this is a file used for activation and I don't want visible too.